# Do something after observable finishes?

Tags: c#, linq, observable

i am using a IObservable to do some loading in the background. i want to specify when this is finished loading. How can i do this only once, instead of every time my data retriver does a yield return? How do I do this?

```
bool IsLoading = true;
ObservableCollection<MyData> dataList = new
ObservableCollection<MyData>();
DataLoader.RetrieveData().ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool).Select(x => x).ObserverOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher).Subscribe(x => {
    dataList.Add(x);
    IsLoading = false;});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the [Finally extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212133%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), it will do exactly what you want!

```
bool IsLoading = true;
ObservableCollection<MyData> dataList = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
DataLoader.RetrieveData()
  .ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
  .Select(x => x)
  .ObserverOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher)
  .Finally(() => IsLoading = false)
  .Subscribe(x => dataList.Add(x));
```

That should execute after the observable sequence is terminated.

Comment: The docs also state that it runs on exception too - is there a way to check for that so the finally code can adapt?  Under an exception, you likely don't want to continue as normal.

Comment: You're right. I'm not certain & I'll have to look in to that and (hopefully) update my answer with something useful!